# Can I use HTML to add hidden text that still gets counted by ctrl+F?

Tags: html, find, hidden-field

I have a string of 1s and 0s that I want to have people count. However, to separate those people who are actually counting from those who are "cheating" by using ctrl+F, I'd like to include a few extra 1's that **do not** appear to people but **would** get counted if someone was using ctrl+F.

In other words, I'd like something to be displayed like this: 1 0 1 1
....but actually have two extra *hidden* 1's so anyone counting would see **three** ones but anyone using ctrl+F would report **five** ones (3 displayed + 2 hidden).

**Is it possible to use HTML to have hidden text that isn't displayed but *is* counted by ctrl+F?**

Here's what the code looks like right now.

```
Count the number of &quot;ones&quot; below:&nbsp;<br />
<br />
1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1
```

I'm new to both HTML and HTML StackOverflow. Thanks so much in advance for any help you might offer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hide the hidden numbers by using a combination of absolute/fixed positioning and top/left translation.

Example:

```css
.hidden {
   position: fixed;
   top: -9999px;
   left: -9999px;
}
```

```html
<span class="hidden">1</span>
<span>1</span>
```

It might be easier to grok if you look at this [codepen](https://codepen.io/sforsberg/full/YzwKvPr).

You will physically see 8 1s in the browser, but `CTRL + F` shows 9.

### Inline Style Example

```html
<span style="position: fixed;top: -9999px;left: -9999px;">1</span>
<span>1</span>
```

Comment: Fantastic. That codepen accomplishes exactly what I was looking for! Thanks!

Comment: That top bloc is CSS, yeah? Is there a way to accomplish this without CSS? I'm implementing in the context of a Qualtrics survey, so can't add/edit CSS (to my knowledge).

Comment: You could do it inline, but that is really messy. I can update my answer. BTW you accepted the other answer...

Comment: Edited my answer with an inline style example.

Comment: Fantastic. That's exactly what I needed. SO grateful. Thanks, segFault!

Answer (score 1):

You can simply place your extra 1s within a span tag and style this with a display of none. These will be hidden and won't show up on the page, and won't be counted when using Ctrl+F to search for 1s:

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<p>
  Count the &quot;ones&quot;:
</p>
<p>
  1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 <span class='hide'>1 1 1</span>
</p>
<p>
  1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 <span style="display:none;">1 1 1</span>
</p>
```

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks a ton!

Comment: That top bloc is CSS, yeah? Is there a way to accomplish this without CSS? I'm implementing in the context of a Qualtrics survey, so can't add/edit CSS (to my knowledge).

Comment: Yes. You can use inline styles in the HTML. I've changed the snippet to give you an example.

Comment: That's perfect. Thanks!